# Set the exception (error handling) to a boolean

Tags: python-3.x

I'm doing a boolean check and I run into several div/0 errors. So I want the error to be set to False so that my output has either True or False. I tried the code below but Python threw a syntax error. Is there a way to go about this?

```
    except ZeroDivisionError as False:
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is attempting to assign a `ZeroDivisionError` object to the name `False`.  There's no good reason to do that, and the language assumes you're making a mistake and won't let you.  (Python 3 does not allow you to assign to `False` at all).

Instead, you should have a variable with a unique name that you use to store whether ot not the error was raised:

```
try:
    1/maybe_zero
    var = True
except ZeroDivisionError:
    var = False
```